# $routeChangeStart not working while there is no otherwise in angular routes

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that is supposed to watch for changes in the routes:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(next, current) {
    // do something
});
```

If i have in my routes file the otherwise action `$stateChangeStart` works as expected. if not it is not called.

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

I am not getting any console errors and i feel i am missing something about how `$routeChangeStart` works.

Comment: listen $stateChangeStart in a config block otherwise you cannot reach that as it is in controller now (you use scope thats why I am telling this) and controller cannot start without state set...

Comment: please post as answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen `$stateChangeStart` in a config block otherwise you cannot reach that as it is in controller now (you use scope thats why I am telling this) and controller cannot start without state set...

You can inject $rootScope to config block and listen events...

Comment: How? 

                .config(["$rootScope", ($rootScope: ng.IScope) => {
...
                    }

Results in:
Failed to instantiate module JPB due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootScope

Answer (score -1):

Use `$rootScope` it should be something like this :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // add your code here
})
```

Comment: @AryehArmon Please provide a fiddle or something to help you better.